# How do I give GLUT cubes different colors?

Tags: opengl, glut

Just what it says:  I have some code that's drawing GLUT cubes, but they're all grey.  How do I make them different colors?

Everything I've tried so far has failed.  I think my problem is that I'm trying to use OpenGL functions to change their colors, but GLUT is maintaining it's own internal color or material data and I don't know how to make it change that data.

This is just filler graphics for a test-client for an online game, so they don't have to look good, I just need to be able to tell things apart.  I know GLUT isn't considered great, so if anyone wants to post an example of drawing a cube with plain OpenGL instead of glutCube I'm all ears.  I don't really care how I get the cubes on the screen, and it's not a part of the code I want to spend a lot of time on.  I have a partner who's doing the real graphics; I just need to get something showing so that I can visualize what my code is doing.

The language I'm using OpenGL/GLUT from is called Io, but the API it exposes should be the same as if I were calling it from C.

Comment: Some code would be useful. Are you using a material? Is there is light source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that if I just do:

```
            glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
```

then it makes the material track whatever color I set with glColor, even when lighting is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the color beforehand with [`glColor()`](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/man_pages/hardcopy/GL/html/gl/color.html).  If you're using lighting (i.e. `GL_LIGHTING` is enabled), though, then you'll instead have to use [`glMaterial()`](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/man_pages/hardcopy/GL/html/gl/material.html) to set the cube's color.

Comment: You might also have a look at the NeHe OpenGL lessons: http://nehe.gamedev.net/lesson.asp?index=01 - They have some basic code for many languages there you could use.

Comment: Could you add an example of some args to give to glMaterial?  Looking at the hyperlink for glMaterial it seems like it's talking about shininess; it's not obvious to me how that relates to color.

I am indeed using GL_LIGHTING, because I found that with lighting turned off it became impossible to distinguish the edges of my shapes.